# Distribution of transformation of conditional random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and let
$Y,S: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be random variables with a density $p:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ wrt. the Lebesgue measure with the property that $p(y,s) > 0$ for all $(y,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Now let $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function and let $X = f(Y)$. I wish to show that for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(Y) |S=s$ and $f(Y | S=s)$ have the same distribution, i.e.
$$
f(Y) |S=s \overset{d} = f(Y | S=s)
$$
which makes intuitive sense, and is shown (in a more complicated version) in Lemma 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3757.pdf .

To show that distributional identity, we will show that the respective densities of the conditional distributions can be chosen to be identical. The following set of equalities
$$
p_{X | S=s}(x) = \frac{p(x,s)}{p(s)} =\frac{\int p_{X | Y = y}(x)p_{Y | S=s}(y)p(s)dy}{p(s)} = \int p_{X | Y = y}(x)p_{Y | S=s}(y)dy=p_{f(Y)|S=s}(x)
$$
seems to be the general idea of the proof. However, many of these equalities are quite confusing, since $p_{X | Y = y}$ is not a density but rather the Dirac measure with point mass in $x$. But then

$$
\int p_{X | Y = y}(x)p_{Y | S=s}(y)dy = \int 1(y=x)p_{Y | S=s}(y)dy=0,
$$
so clearly there are some technicalities I am missing. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Work-in-progress solution:
Let $\rho$ denote the probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2))$ associated with the random variables $(S, Y):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\tilde{\rho}$ denote the probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2))$ associated with the random variables $(S,f(Y)):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$. For both $\rho$ and $\tilde{\rho}$, there exists disintegrations of the form
$$
\rho = \nu \otimes \mu, \quad \tilde{\rho} = \tilde{\nu} \otimes \tilde{\mu}
$$
where $\nu, \tilde{\nu}$ are probability measures and $\mu, \tilde{\mu}$ are probability kernels. In other words, $\mu = (\mu_s)_{s\in \mathbb{R}}$ and $(\tilde{\mu}_s)_{s\in \mathbb{R}}$ are collections of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with the intuition that
$$
\mu_s(B) =  P(Y \in B ~ | ~ S =s), \quad \tilde{\mu}(B) =  P(f(Y) \in B ~ | ~ S =s)
$$
and $\nu, \tilde{\nu}$ are to be regarded as the image measure of $S$ (and thus $\nu = \tilde{\nu}$). For the disintegrations, we have for $f \geq 0$ that
$$
(\nu \otimes \mu) f = \int \int f(s,y) d\mu_s(y) d \nu (s)
$$
Now, what we wish to show is then
$$
f_{*} \mu_s = \tilde{\mu}_s \quad \text{a.e.}[P_S].
$$
Here, $f_{*} \mu_s$ denotes the pushforward measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_* \mu(B) = \mu ( f^{-1}(B)).$
We can first show that for any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have
$$
f_{*} \mu_s (B) = \tilde{\mu}_s(B) \quad \text{a.e.}[P_S]
$$
Proof: letting $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$
h(s,y) = (s,f(y))
$,
we have that the pushforward measure $h_{*} \rho$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the property that $h_{*} \rho = \tilde{\rho}$. Thus, for any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ it holds that
$$h_{*} \rho ( \mathbb{R} \times B ) = \tilde{\rho}(\mathbb{R} \times B),$$ and
$$h_{*} \rho ( \mathbb{R} \times B )
=
\rho ( \mathbb{R} \times f^{-1}(B) )
=
\int \int 1_{f^{-1}(B)}(y) d \mu_s(y) d \nu (s)
=
\int \mu_s(f^{-1}(B)) d\nu(s)
=
\int f_* \mu(B) d\nu(s)
$$
and
$$
\tilde{\rho}(\mathbb{R} \times B) 
=
\int \int 1_{B}(x) d\tilde{\mu}_s(x) d \nu(s)
=
\int \tilde{\mu}_s(B)d \nu(s)
$$
However, this does not quite give the desired result, since the exception-set might be $B$-dependent: even though it holds that for any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
f_{*} \mu_s (B) = \tilde{\mu}_s(B) \quad \text{a.e.}[P_S]
$$
it does not imply that
$$
f_{*} \mu_s = \tilde{\mu}_s \quad \text{a.e.}[P_S]
$$
I wonder how to extend the above argument in a uniform way to ensure that we have equality almost surely between the two bundles of measures.

Comment: That's not how Dirac deltas work:
$$\int \delta(y,x) f(y)\,dy= f(x)$$
So
$$\int p_{X|Y=y}(x)p_{Y|S=s}(y)\,dy=p_{Y|S=s}(x)$$

Comment: I am not sure I understand the potential distinction between $f(Y) \mid S=s$ and $f(Y  \mid S=s)$ unless they both mean $f_{Y  \mid S=s}(Y)$

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thank you. That explains the notation. After having thought about it, the problem seems perhaps a bit broken/need to be careful without more assumptions on $f$, since $f(Y)$ might not even have a density wrt. the Lebesgue measure if $f$ is constant on some interval.

Comment: @Henry $f(Y) | S=s $ is a random variable associated to the conditional distribution of $f(Y)$ given $S=s$, and $f(Y | S=s)$ is a transformation by $f$ of the random variable associated to the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $S =s$. The question is then if the distributions of these r.v. are identical.

Comment: I am still not seeing the potential distinction.  I would have though both involve changing the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, perhaps by shrinking the sample space from $\Omega$ to $\Omega_{S=s}= \{\omega \in \Omega: S(\omega)=s\}$ or perhaps by changing $P$ so $P_{S=s}(S\not = s)=0$ while retaining $P_{S=s}(\Omega)=1$

Comment: @Henry The first expression transforms $Y$ and then conditions on $S$. The second expression does it the other way around. Also you are taking the equation $S=s$ too literally. This event is a null set in this setting.

Comment: If you don't have densities, you're going to need a substantially more complicated argument using either conditional expectations or disintegrations.

Comment: @ThomasLumley That is a good point, thank you. I have tried to use the disintegration theorem to prove the statement. I have updated my question with a work in progress proof, however, theres still a piece that seems to be missing. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I believe I found the solution - will post tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did seems correct. I would prove it as follows: $f(Y \vert S)$ is the pushforward of the (random) distribution $Y \vert S$. The latter can be defined via its regular conditional probability, i.e. via
$$
\kappa_{Y \vert S} ( \cdot , A) = \mathbb{E} ( \mathbb{I}_{Y \in A} \vert S) 
$$
where $\kappa_{Y \vert S} : \Omega \times \mathcal{B} \to [0,1]$ is a regular transition kernel. In particular, we know that for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$ the mapping $A \mapsto \kappa_{Y \vert S} (\omega , A)$ is a probability measure, so we can compute its pushforward measure under $f$. For almost all $\omega$ and any measurable $B$ we get
$$
f_* (\kappa_{Y \vert S} (\omega , \cdot))(B) = \kappa_{Y \vert S} (\omega, f^{-1} (B)) = \mathbb{E} ( \mathbb{I}_{Y \in f^{-1}(B)} \vert S)(\omega) = \mathbb{E} ( \mathbb{I}_{f(Y) \in B} \vert S)(\omega).
$$
So $f_* (\kappa_{Y \vert S} (\cdot, \cdot)) (B)$ is a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{f(Y) \in B} \vert S)$ and thus agrees with the regular conditional probability of $f(Y) \vert S$.